# How to render glyphs from FontAwesome on a Canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webfonts

[FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome) specifies glyphs in its CSS file like so:

```
/*  Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure 
    screen readers do not read off random characters that represent icons */
.icon-glass:before                { content: "\f000"; }
.icon-music:before                { content: "\f001"; }
```

I am trying to render icons from this font to a canvas element but can't see how to access these glyphs.

```
ctx.font = "40px FontAwesome";
ctx.fillText("\f000",20,20); // no cigar
```

How do I specify these glyphs in JavaScript strings?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) :

```
ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode("0xf000"), 20, 20);
```

or this syntax for Unicode escapes :

```
ctx.fillText("\uf000", 20, 20);
```

Comment: This worked for me, using this format: `createjs.Text('\uf178', '100px FontAwesome, 'red')`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got here looking to render Material Design Icons on a canvas. For me, `String.fromCodePoint(0xF0625)` did the trick. Where `F0909` corresponds to the value found in the CSS `content` attribute: `.mdi-help-circle-outline::before { content: "\F0625"; }`

Comment: Be careful, String.fromCodePoint is not implemented by all browsers (IE again) :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint