# Set Font Awesome icons as cursor - is this possible?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas, font-awesome

Font Awesome has a very good collection of icons to be used in web projects. I want to use one of those icons as cursor (custom cursor).

In my understanding, Custom Cursors need an image url, but I am unable to find the image urls for Font Awesome icons.

Comment: I don't think you can specify text/font for the cursor. You may need to create an image with the icon that you want from Font Awesome, and then use it for the cursor with `cursor: url(...)`

Comment: I think I can di it, first create a canvas, then draw the fa icon on it, then change it into a base-64 image, then reference it. I'm trying to code it, wait for me!

Comment: It would be nice to see some of your existing code.

Comment: @fish_ball that sounds like a lot of effort just to avoid creating an image beforehand. Although it sounds like an interesting challenge, now I want to try too

Comment: @Monty82, @ fish_ball : Thank you for the suggestions. will create the image beforehand and use it for cursor. Thanks.

Comment: quite related jQuery plugin: https://jwarby.github.io/jquery-awesome-cursor/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Got it!

1. Create a canvas
2. Draw the fa icon on it
3. Change it into a base-64 image url
4. Apply the image on the cursor css style

And I made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rqq8B/2/

```js
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761472/how-to-render-glyphs-from-fontawesome-on-a-canvas-element
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932291/css-cursor-using-data-uri

$(function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 24;
    canvas.height = 24;
    //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "24px FontAwesome";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText("\uf002", 12, 12);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    $('body').css('cursor', 'url('+dataURL+'), auto');
});
```

```css
body {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the JSfiddle, I'm seeing the custom element frame / placeholder, but not an actual element.  How are you loading the fontawesome elements?  Am I doing this right? Do I have to add in the CDN link for the fontawesome library?

Comment: "\uf002" in FontAwesome represents a placeholder like character, change that - say "\uf001" - you should see a different cursor.

Comment: I understand. I now see the font-awesome.css in the external resources on the left hand margin.  What I'm not seeing are results in the JSFiddle.  I see an empty box for a cursor.. Ooops. Update.  Works fine on Chrome browser, just not on Firefox (win7).  Ugh. I hate when things work fine in one browser, but not in another.

Comment: Doens't work in my chrome either. I just see "FL" as my cursor

Comment: I'm trying to use fa-crosshairs with crosshair arg instead of auto but still couldn't get it to draw in the center of the icon. :(

Comment: For those seeing "FL", looks like you need to force the font to load by adding a font tag in the HTML code.

http://jsfiddle.net/rna9qv6m/

Comment: This does not work in Internet Explorer or Edge in windows 10. Works in Firefox though

Comment: Doesn't work in IE11 as well. @olragon your link is unreachable too.

Answer (score 15):

In the end, I couldn't get @fish_ball's code working reliably, so I just [downloaded the images](http://www.flaticon.com/packs/font-awesome), used [gimp](http://www.gimp.org) to crop and edit them to 32×32px, and used them like this:

```
.myClass { cursor: url('/static/img/pencil30_32x32.png') 1 30, crosshair }
```

The `1 30` part sets the mouse pointer 'hotspot' 1px from the left and 30px from the top of the image.

Comment: To whomever downvoted my answer: It would be helpful if you followed the instructions and left a comment saying why. If you have a better answer, it would help everybody if you posted it. @fish_ball's code only works in some browsers, though, even with the <font> tag.

Comment: More downvotes, and still no explanations!  Apparently a lot of people don't understand how a community can work together to help everybody.

Answer (score 10):

There is [jQuery Awesome Cursor](https://jwarby.github.io/jquery-awesome-cursor/), where you can add font-awesome icons to your cursor by calling only one simple code:

```
$('body').awesomeCursor('pencil');
```

Or passing it some options:

```
$('body').awesomeCursor('pencil', {
  /* your options here */
  size: 22,
  color: 'orange',
  flip: 'horizontal'
});
```

Disclaimer: I am NOT the author of this library I have just found it.

Comment: I will add that this library also works with other icon fonts (ex. icomoon)

Comment: I spent about a day of R&D trying out the solutions that are supposed to force pre-loading the font, and nothing worked except for the [jquery-awesome-cursor library](https://jwarby.github.io/jquery-awesome-cursor/)

Comment: nice lib, but how the heck unset custom cursor?? (docs have nothing about this)

Answer (score 8):

The canvas method mentioned results in blurry cursors.

Using SVG offers better results:

- Download the SVG for the icon you want to use from [Encharm's Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/svg).
- Edit the SVG using a text editor and specify the width and height you'd like to use

  - e.g.: 24 x 24.
  - Keep in mind there's usually a maximum size in the browser (128 x 128 in Firefox.)
- Declare the cursor in CSS, e.g.: `cursor: url( '/assets/img/volume-up.svg' ), pointer;`

Comment: I wanted to highlight that the resizing step is required!

Comment: SVG is better than canvas for a number of reasons.. SVG is more deterministic, whereas canvas you have to ask, "was this drawn?",  "If I resized it, was it re-drawn?"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Vue.js, there is an easier approach:

Importing font awesome icon as a component:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';

library.add(fas);
library.add(fab);
library.add(far);
Vue.component('fa-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
```

and using it directly in the HTML of a page:

```
<fa-icon icon="copy" @click="yourFunction"/>
```

and surrounding your  tag with `<span>`:

```
<span class="hover"><fa-icon icon="copy" @click="yourFunction"/></span>
```

and adding to your css:

```
span.hover { 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

This will add a pointer on all `<span>` tags with class `hover` in your code (and thus your font awesome icons !)

Comment: Is there a way we can have a small tooltip sort of text appear when someone hovers over the font-awesome icon with custom text?

Comment: Bootstrap can help you do that easily: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip

Comment: @marcvander, I thought the original question was to make the cursor of mouse to be a custom icon from Font Awesome. If I understood correctly, your solution would show the browser's built-in "pointer" cursor (not custom cursor) when the user hovers the mouse over the "copy" icon?

Comment: @hyong Yes indeed, my code does that. Then I might have misunderstood the original question