# Assign Font Awesome icon to cursor on hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to use one of Font Awesome icons as the cursor/mouse pointer when I hover over a div. Is this possible? something like this:

```
.myClass:hover {
    cursor: <--- here assign to the cursor the Font Awesome icon
}
```

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093263/set-font-awesome-icons-as-cursor-is-this-possible

Comment: Or this: https://jwarby.github.io/jquery-awesome-cursor/

Comment: That works, however I'm trying to avoid using jquery

Comment: The cursor property is expecting an url to an image, so what you can do is save the desired icon as an image. Here's a library of svgs[1] from where you can save a png with the size that fits your requirement. Then use cursor: url(fa-icon.png),auto; I don't think there's any other way at the moment that can solve this with pure CSS. [https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/svg]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp), the only way to achieve a custom cursor, 
is by using `cursor: url();`

#### So, tagging along with @RicardoRuiz 's answer:

- someone created a [fontawesome to png generator](http://fa2png.io/)
- download the .png icon,
- store it inside your project assets directory or online `e.g. dropbox`
- use CSS `cursor: url()` to use the icon image as a cursor.

Comment: Just wanted to add that url("imageLink") wasn't working for me until i added "auto" value to it, as in cursor: url("imageLink"), auto;