# html change cursor style to pen

Tags: html, css

```
 style="cursor:"
```

Is that possible change the mouse cursor to pen?

I only found few style from the google:

```html
 <span style="cursor:auto">auto</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:crosshair">crosshair</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:default">default</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:e-resize">e-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:grab">grab</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:help">help</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:move">move</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:n-resize">n-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:ne-resize">ne-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:nw-resize">nw-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:pointer">pointer</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:progress">progress</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:s-resize">s-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:se-resize">se-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:sw-resize">sw-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:text">text</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:w-resize">w-resize</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:wait">wait</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:not-allowed">not-allowed</span><br>
    <span style="cursor:no-drop">no-drop</span><br>
```

I need pen style because I want when user mouseover to the **convas** div, I want user sign on the field

Comment: post with example. what you need?

Comment: i need cursor style with pen shape..

Comment: yes, use custom image, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors

Comment: helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093263/set-font-awesome-icons-as-cursor-is-this-possible

Comment: <canvas id="colors_sketch"  style="cursor:url('/Images/pen.png')"></canvas>,not working..

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom cursors: Below code will give you an idea

```
body {
 cursor: url('some-cursor.ico'), default;
}
```

Comment: <canvas id="colors_sketch"  style="cursor:url('/Images/pen.png')"></canvas>  ,mouse cursor remain default,something wrong with my code?

Comment: This does not work. ico files do not get rendered to canvas cursor styles.