# Vis.js font-awesome icons rendered as characters

Tags: unicode, font-awesome, vis.js

I am using visjs with angular to render a simple network, the icons are loaded properly locally.

[image]

But when hosted, actual unicode characters are rendered.

Fontawesome icons outside of canvas are loaded, but within the network this happens.

[image: **enter image description here**]

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761472/how-to-render-glyphs-from-fontawesome-on-a-canvas-element) related?

Comment: I have no problem with rendering, I am not sure what is missing because it works locally but not when hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost a week I found out the problem was default encoding used by Tomcat.

Make the following change in `tomcat/conf/web.xml`

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

To

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>application/javascript;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```